# Issue with conditional expression in Access

Tags: ms-access

Essentially I would like to look at a form text box to determine what criteria to add to a `SELECT` Query in Access.

In a form I have 2 textboxes one representing the `dateStart` and one for `dateEnd`. If dateStart is empty the expression should default the criteria to todays date using `Date()`, and otherwise take the date range between the 2 text boxes.

The following is my current expression:

```
IIf(IsNull([Forms]![HomeForm]![dateStart]),Date(),Between [Forms]![HomeForm]![dateStart] And [Forms]![HomeForm]![dateEnd])
```

For some reason when the `dateStart`, `dateEnd` fields have a date I get no results.

**Note:** By itself the Between expression works with no issue, its only when inside the conditional that the issue occurs.

Comment: This is in WHERE clause of query object?

Answer (score 1):

The BETWEEN AND keywords cannot be conditional. Conditional needs to be on each parameter input. Use IIf() with IS NULL or Nz().

`Between Nz([Forms]![HomeForm]![dateStart], Date()) And Nz([Forms]![HomeForm]![dateEnd],Date())`

Alternatively, instead of dynamic paramterized query, use VBA to conditionally build filter criteria and apply to form or report.